# What does <xsd:include schemaLocation="some.xsd" /> mean

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

Could anyone please explain what the following line in my xsd mean ?

```
<xsd:include schemaLocation="Some_schema.xsd" />
```

How is it used ? The XSD is pretty large so i cant paste it here. Can anyone please give a simple example using the following that explains how two schemas can be integrated ?

```
 <xsd:include schemaLocation="Some_schema.xsd" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty much the same as "include" in any programming language: it means, treat the contents of the schema document at "someSchema.xsd" as if they were part of this schema document. The detailed semantics are more subtle, but that's the simple explanation.